# Python integer to read-only buffer

Tags: python, binary, cdb

I am using cdb for a constant database in python.  I would like to associate integer id's with some strings, and I would like to avoid storing each of these integer id's as strings, and instead store them as an integer.  cdb though is looking for either a string or a read only buffer.  Is there a way that I can store these keys as integers instead of strings?

For example:

```
cdb = cdb.cdbmake("test.cdb","test.cdb.tmp")
key = 5
value = "some test string"

#this throws an error
maker.add(key,value)
#TypeError: add() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not int

#this would work, but seems inefficient
maker.add(str(key),value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [cdb website](http://cr.yp.to/cdb/cdb.txt) the database only takes strings as keys

> A cdb is an associative array: it maps strings (keys) to strings (data).

So you will have to convert the integers to strings first.  I suggest you wrap the `str` in a utility function and forget about the overhead.